# Process exceeding max open files limit

Tags: files, limit, file-descriptors

I am counting current open files by a process pid by :-
cmd1:-

```
ls /proc/$pid/fd/* | wc -l
```

and then I am calculating percentage by fetching Max open Files limits.
cmd2:-

```
$ cat /proc/$pid/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units

Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max processes             30425                30425                processes
Max open files            4096                 4096                 files
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
```

Only pasting part of output.

I am calculating percentage :-

cmd1/cmd2*100

i.e if `ls /proc/$pid/fd/* | wc -l` gives 1000.
then percentage will be :- 
1000/4096*100= approx 25%

sometimes I am getting this percentage as 220.

scenario is  reproducible now,it happened in one  server and I found that in 
`/proc/pid/fd/29`: there are 5000 log files opened by a process.

It means process pid is crossing the Max open file limits(4096 ) .

Answer (score 1):

Note that the limit is on the value of newly created file descriptors (as in `open()`/`socket()`/`pipe()` and so on will never return a number greater than `n-1` if the limit was set to `n`, and `dup2(1, n or n+1...)` will fail), not on the number of currently open files or file descriptors.

In effect, from the instant the limit is set to `n`, that will prevent that process from opening more than `n` files, but if file descriptors above `n` had already been created before the limit was lowered, then the process can possibly have more than `n` files open.

Example:

```
$ limit descriptors 10000 # ulimit -n 10000 in bash
$ perl -MBSD::Resource -MPOSIX -e '
    dup2(1,$_) for (2000..4000);
    setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, 1024, 1024);
    exec zsh'
zsh$ ls /proc/$$/fd | wc -w
2009
zsh$ readlink /proc/$$/fd/3000
/dev/pts/1
zsh$ repeat 100 exec {a}>&1
zsh$ ls /proc/$$/fd | wc -w
2109
zsh$ grep files /proc/$$/limits
Max open files            1024                 1024                 files
```

At the time `zsh` was executed, the process had fds 2000 to 4000 open to `/dev/pts/1`. Yet the fd limit was 1024.

It already had 2009 fds, but was still able to create 100 more.